# group and classify words as well as characters

Tags: python, nltk, hunspell

I need to split on slash and then report tags. This is hunspell dictionary format. I tried to find a class on github that would do this, but could not find one.

```
# vi test.txt
test/S
boy
girl/SE
home/
house/SE123
man/E
country
wind/ES
```

The code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
myl=defaultdict(list)

with open('test.txt') as f :
    for l in f:
        l = l.rstrip()
        try:
            tags = l.split('/')[1]
            myl[tags].append(l.split('/')[0])
            for t in tags:
                myl[t].append( l.split('/')[0])
        except:
            pass
```

output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'S': ['test', 'test', 'girl', 'house', 'wind'],
             'SE': ['girl'],
             'E': ['girl', 'house', 'man', 'man', 'wind'],
             '': ['home'],
             'SE123': ['house'],
             '1': ['house'],
             '2': ['house'],
             '3': ['house'],
             'ES': ['wind']})
```

SE group should have 3 words 'girl', 'wind' and 'house'. There should be no ES group because it is included and same as "SE" and SE123 should remain as is. how do I achieve this?

---

Update:

I have managed to add bigrams, but how do I add 3, 4, 5 grams?

```
from collections import defaultdict
import nltk
myl=defaultdict(list)

with open('hi_IN.dic') as f :
    for l in f:
        l = l.rstrip()
        try:
            tags = l.split('/')[1]
            ntags=''.join(sorted(tags))
            myl[ntags].append(l.split('/')[0])
            for t in tags:
                myl[t].append( l.split('/')[0])
            bigrm = list(nltk.bigrams([i for i in tags]))
            nlist=[x+y for x, y in bigrm]
            for t1 in nlist:
                t1a=''.join(sorted(t1))
                myl[t1a].append(l.split('/')[0])
        except:
            pass
```

---

I guess it would help if I sort the tags at source:

```
with open('test1.txt', 'w') as nf:
    with open('test.txt') as f :
        for l in f:
            l = l.rstrip()
            try:
                tags = l.split('/')[1]
            except IndexError:
                nline= l 
            else:
                ntags=''.join(sorted(tags))
                nline= l.split('/')[0] + '/' + ntags
            nf.write(nline+'\n')
```

This will create a new file test1.txt with sorted tags. But the problem of trigrams+ still not resolved.

---

I downloaded a sample file:

!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wooorm/dictionaries/master/dictionaries/en-US/index.dic

The report using "grep" command is correct.

```
!grep 'P.*U' index1.dic

CPU/M
GPU
aware/PU
cleanly/PRTU
common/PRTUY
conscious/PUY
easy/PRTU
faithful/PUY
friendly/PRTU
godly/PRTU
grateful/PUY
happy/PRTU
healthy/PRTU
holy/PRTU
kind/PRTUY
lawful/PUY
likely/PRTU
lucky/PRTU
natural/PUY
obtrusive/PUY
pleasant/PTUY
prepared/PU
reasonable/PU
responsive/PUY
righteous/PU
scrupulous/PUY
seemly/PRTU
selfish/PUY
timely/PRTU
truthful/PUY
wary/PRTU
wholesome/PU
willing/PUY
worldly/PTU
worthy/PRTU
```

The python report using bigrams on sorted tags file does not contain all the words mentioned above.

```
myl['PU']

['aware',
 'aware',
 'conscious',
 'faithful',
 'grateful',
 'lawful',
 'natural',
 'obtrusive',
 'prepared',
 'prepared',
 'reasonable',
 'reasonable',
 'responsive',
 'righteous',
 'righteous',
 'scrupulous',
 'selfish',
 'truthful',
 'wholesome',
 'wholesome',
 'willing']
```

Comment: It seems more manageable if you split this into 2 steps in my opinion. 1.Create the set of keys for each tag 2. Loop through your list of value/tag and append the value to each of the keys for that tag

Comment: Is 5-gram the maximum that you need or would you need 6-gram if there was 6 tags? Do you need also skipragams, like `S1`, `S2`? Do you all combinatinos of the tags?

Comment: Yes. I need all combinations of tags. It includes skipgrams and 5-grams, 6-grams depending upon the number of tags used. In other words I need a report of how the words are tagged. for e.g. from this file https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries/blob/master/dictionaries/en-US/index.dic

Answer (score 5):

Given I understand it correctly, this is more a matter of constructing a datastructure that, for a given tag, *constructs* the correct list. We can do this by constructing a dictionary that only takes into account singular tags. Later, when a person queries on multiple tags, we calculate the intersection. This thus makes it compact to represent, as well as easy to extract for example all the elements with tag `AC` and this will list elements with tag `ABCD`, `ACD`, `ZABC`, etc.

We can thus construct a parser:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Hunspell(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, tags):
        if not tags:
            return self.data.get(None, [])

        elements = [self.data.get(tag ,()) for tag in tags]
        data = set.intersection(*map(set, elements))
        return [e for e in self.data.get(tags[0], ()) if e in data]

    @staticmethod
    def load(f):
       data = defaultdict(list)
       for line in f:
           try:
               element, tags = line.rstrip().split('/', 1)
               for tag in tags:
                   data[tag].append(element)
               data[None].append(element)
           except ValueError:
               pass  # element with no tags
       return Hunspell(dict(data))
```

The list processing at the end of `__getitem__` is done to retrieve the elements in the correct order.

We can then load the file into memory with:

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
...     h = Hunspell.load(f)
```

and query it for arbitrary keys:

```
>>> h['SE']
['girl', 'house', 'wind']
>>> h['ES']
['girl', 'house', 'wind']
>>> h['1']
['house']
>>> h['']
['test', 'girl', 'home', 'house', 'man', 'wind']
>>> h['S3']
['house']
>>> h['S2']
['house']
>>> h['SE2']
['house']
>>> h[None]
['test', 'girl', 'home', 'house', 'man', 'wind']
>>> h['4']
[]
```

querying for non-existing tags will result in an empty list. Here we thus postpone the "intersection" process upon calling. We can in fact already generate all possible intersections, but this will result in a large datastructure, and perhaps a large amount of work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myl=dict()
with open('test.txt') as f :
    for l in f:
        l = l.rstrip()
        try:
            tags = l.split('/')[1]
            myl.setdefault(tags,[])
            myl[tags].append(l.split('/')[0])
            for t in tags:
                myl.setdefault(t,[])
                myl[t].append( l.split('/')[0])
        except:
            pass
keys=myl.keys()
for k1 in keys:
    for k2 in keys:
        if len(set(k1).intersection(k2))==len(set(k1)) and k1!=k2:
            myl[k1].extend([myk2v for myk2v in myl[k2] if myk2v not in myl[k1]]) 
print(myl)
```

**Output**

```
{'S': ['test', 'test', 'girl', 'house', 'wind'], 'SE': ['girl', 'house', 'wind'], 'E': ['girl', 'house', 'man', 'man', 'wind'], '': ['home', 'test', 'test', 'girl', 'house', 'wind', 'man', 'man'], 'SE123': ['house'], '1': ['house'], '2': ['house'], '3': ['house'], 'ES': ['wind', 'girl', 'house']}
```

In the last two for loops of the program, the set of `k1` and `k2` are taken first, and then, the intersection of the two sets is compared. If the length of the intersection is equal to the length of set `k1`, the value of the key `k2` should be in the key `k1`, so the value of the key `k2` is added to the key `k1`.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler Version of what [willem van onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) already answered

```
data = defaultdict(list)
with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        try:
            element,tags = line.rstrip().split('/', 1)
            print(element)
            for tag in tags:
                data[tag].append(element)
                data[None].append(element)
        except ValueError:
            pass

def parse(data,tag):
    if(tag==None or tag==''):
        return set(data[None])
    elements = [set(data[tag_i]) for tag_i in tag]
    return set.intersection(*map(set, elements))



>>> parse(data,'ES') 
>>> {'girl', 'house', 'wind'}
>>> parse(data,None)
>>> {'girl', 'house', 'man', 'wind'}
>>> parse(data,'')
>>> {'girl', 'house', 'man', 'wind'}
```